# How To Make Streams in flutter dart work with provider

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

This was working initially and it just stopped and I cannot figure out where the problem lies.

I am working with streams on my flutter project in provider package. Streams are being emitted from services files and listening is happening on the widgets file. Firebase onAuthStateChanged stream is working but mine are not working.

I have alot of code in my files so am not going to post everything here.

I have a problem with AuthStatus stream
I tried subscribing to the stream on the widget class but it seems like no streams are getting emitted

```
  MyApp(){
    auth.authStateStream.listen((d){print("$d is data");});
  }
```

This how firebase streams are getting emiited from services file

```
  Stream<UserModel> get onAuthStateChanged{
      return _firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged.map(_userFromFirebase);
  }
```

I have a problem with AuthStatus stream. This was working initially
This is how AuthStatus stream is getting emmited from services file

```
  //Services file
  final StreamController<AuthStatus> _currentAuthStateController =
      StreamController<AuthStatus>.broadcast();

  Stream<AuthStatus> get authStateStream{
    return _currentAuthStateController.stream;
  }


  void testStremas() {
    //Stoast.setMessage("Test Message");
    _currentAuthStateController.add(AuthStatus.ACTIVE);
  }
```

This is how provider is litening to streams as a parent of the MaterialAPP widget

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  //I was trying if i my widget could subscribe to the stream
  MyApp (){
    auth.authStateStream.listen((d){print("$d is data");});
  }
  final ToastHelper toast = ToastHelper();

  final ThemeHelper theme = ThemeHelper();

  final AuthService auth = AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<UserModel>.value(value: auth.onAuthStateChanged),
        StreamProvider<ToastMessage>.value(value: toast.onNewMessage),
        StreamProvider<AuthStatus>.value(
            value: auth.authStateStream, initialData: AuthStatus.NONE),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: Strings.appName,
        theme: theme.darkThemeData(),
        home: Loader(),
        routes: {
          'home': (context) => Home(),
        },
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is how the above method is getting called on a the widget on a click of a button

```
 //Widgets file 
  onTap: () => auth.testStremas(),
```

The expected result should be when the AuthStatus change from the services file, The widgets should be notified via the provider package. Thanks in advance

```
Widget _body(BuildContext context) {
    final AuthStatus _authStatus = Provider.of<AuthStatus>(context);
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 300),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Center(
              child: _authStatus == AuthStatus.ACTIVE
                  ? Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child:CircularProgressIndicator(strokeWidth: 2,)
                  )
                  : _buildScreen(context),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure - try to change

```
final StreamController<AuthStatus> _currentAuthStateController =
  StreamController<AuthStatus>.broadcast();
```

to

```
final StreamController<AuthStatus> _currentAuthStateController =
  BehaviorSubject<AuthStatus>();
```

This BehaviorSubject from rxdart library https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart, so, you should import it. BehaviorSubject is keep last state of stream. You can read more here https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/BehaviorSubject-class.html

```
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
```